# Inc-Dec-Value packages for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

I hope this is the [right place to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204517/where-to-ask-questions-about-programming-tools-recommendations). SuperUser has much less audience to my question.

Migrating from Sublime to VCS - and I miss on package:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Inc-Dec-Value

Found the package already for Atom, PhpStorm ... But nothing for VSC.

Basically you can increase / decrease of numbers, dates, hex color values with <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>arrow up/down</kbd>

Maybe someone knows something which works similar?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Incrementor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nmsmith89.incrementor) by Neil Smith:

> A Visual Studio Code extension that enables advanced increment /
> decrement actions for numbers, enumerators, or just about anything
> else!

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but sadly it does not change the case of the words.

Comment: You can fork it and add those features. This extension looks abandoned anyway.